# git push heroku: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, heroku

I couldn't find the exactly same problem so here is my question. I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku:

- First I run **heroku create** and I got this:

  > Creating **pure-citadel-7201**... done, stack is cedar
  >   http://pure-citadel-7201.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:pure-citadel-7201.git
- Then I run **git push heroku master** and I got the problem:

  > !  No such app as **pure-castle-7198**.
  >
  > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  >
  > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  >   and the repository exists.

It says there is no `pure-castle-7198` app because I deleted it a long time ago, the one I've created now is `citadel-7201`, so how can I push to this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the git remote to the correct repository. This may mess up if you are using the same repository clone.

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:pure-citadel-7201.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Like iltempo said, your git remotes are creating troubles.. Try to delete Old remote and create new one...
Check available git remotes: (from your app dir)

`git remote -v`

see if you find old remote.. delete it

```
git remote rm remoteName
```

create new remote if not available,

```
git remote add remoteName git@heroku.com:xxxx-xxxxxxxx-8745.git
```

Comment: Thanks @palak-darji !